# Can't find extension NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a program which uses a NetLogo Headless Workspace.

The program work fine, but when I add and the code extensions [sound]

The program raises the error mentioned below. It seems a problem of directories but I am unable to find the bug.

Any help will be highly apppreciated.

```
C:\Users\cmartise\Desktop\ecj>java    -cp "C:\Users\cmartise\Documents\NetBeansProj
ects\prueba\build\classes\;C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0\app\*" prueba.Prueba
main
C:\Users\cmartise\Desktop\ecj\ec\app\model0
    Can't find extension: sound at position 12 in
        at org.nlogo.core.ErrorSource.signalError(ErrorSource.scala:11)
        at org.nlogo.workspace.ExtensionManager.importExtension(ExtensionManager
        .scala:186)
        at org.nlogo.parse.StructureParser$.$anonfun$parsingWithExtensions$1(Str
        uctureParser.scala:71)
        at org.nlogo.parse.StructureParser$.$anonfun$parsingWithExtensions$1$ada
        pted(StructureParser.scala:69)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:378)
        at org.nlogo.parse.StructureParser$.parsingWithExtensions(StructureParse
        r.scala:69)
        at org.nlogo.parse.StructureParser$.parseSources(StructureParser.scala:3
        5)
        at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.basicParse(NetLogoParser.scala:17)
        at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.basicParse$(NetLogoParser.scala:15)
        at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.basicParse(FrontEnd.scala:10)
        at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEndMain.frontEnd(FrontEnd.scala:27)
        at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEndMain.frontEnd$(FrontEnd.scala:25)
        at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.frontEnd(FrontEnd.scala:10)
        at org.nlogo.compile.CompilerMain$.compile(CompilerMain.scala:38)
        at org.nlogo.compile.Compiler.compileProgram(Compiler.scala:52)
        at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessModelOpener.openFromModel(HeadlessModelOpe
        ner.scala:54)
        at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.openModel(HeadlessWorkspace.scal
        a:530)
        at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.open(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:497
        )
        at prueba.Prueba$1.run(Prueba.java:36)
```

Comment: perhaps useful here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API#current-working-directory

Comment: Yes the problema was that the environment variable extensions was not set. Adding, the following text to the call, the problema was solved. -Dnetlogo.extensions.dir="C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0\app\extensions". Thanks for your help.